# How to execute asynctask in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have 3 pager views. When i try to execute asynctask the app crashes because all the task starts simultaneously. I want to perform asynctask for the pager which is currently visible. How do i do that?

Pager 1:

```
public class test extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private MyAsyncTask mAuthTask = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View test = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
        ((TextView)test.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("test");
        return test;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }


    public void attemptLogin() {

        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }
        mAuthTask = new MyAsyncTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }



    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "Loading Explore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // my network operation



            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your crash log.

Comment: you can Happily execute more than one  Asynctask also at This purpose.

Comment: I think it's a structure issue : you shouldn't execute async in a page of your ViewPager but in the activity/fragment instanciating the viewPager.

Comment: @AmitabhaBiswas What do you mean by that? The order that the methods are listed is irrelevant. They will be called in the order that AsyncTask is built.

Comment: AsyncTask callback function should be proper... firstly preExecute secondly DoinBackground and finally PostExecte.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this...**

//call/execute Asynktask

```
new myAsyncTask().execute();
```

// code sample of AsynTask

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        JSONObject jObject;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
     // doing bakground task

      return null;
        }
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

The **BaseAsyncTask** clas is :

```
public class BaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String  doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }



    public static String GET(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }


}
```

and Use it in where you want   like this :

```
baseAsyncTask = new BaseAsyncTask();
        baseAsyncTask.execute(apiUrl);
        try {
            result = baseAsyncTask.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException f) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            f.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ViewPager.onPageChangeListener pagelistener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // Check if this is the page you want.
    }
 });

 pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pagelistener);
```

Call the asynctask inside onPageSelected

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have populated the ViewPager with Fragments:

I don't know why your app would be crashing just because you launch an AsyncTask but if you want to figure out which fragment is visible within the ViewPager you override the Fragment method `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`

So like this:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        startMyAsync();
    }else{
        startMyAsyncWithDelay();
    }
}
```